# what happened to my program files after factory resetting

Tags: windows-10, reset

I just reset my windows 10 laptop with the keep my files option. It has uninstalled all my programs (as I wanted) however has not freed up any space on my drive. Where are my program files from before? I do not have enough spare space to install the hundreds of GB of programs that have been "uninstalled" so need an a solution fast.

Comment: Tried running [Disk Cleanup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026616/windows-disk-cleanup-in-windows-10)? Under the "cleanup System files" options you might find a "previous installations" or similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also remove Windows.old file after reset your PC.

Step 1: Click in Windows' search field, type Cleanup, then click Disk Cleanup.

Step 2: Click the "Clean up system files" button.

Step 3: Wait a bit while Windows scans for files, then scroll down the list until you see "**Previous Windows installation(s)**."

[image]

Step 4: Check the box next to the entry, then make sure there are no other boxes checked (unless you do indeed want to delete those items). Click OK to start the cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

The program files may be in the [*C:\Windows.old*](https://www.howtogeek.com/223821/what-is-the-windows.old-folder-and-how-do-you-delete-it/) folder, where they take up space *until you perform cleanup* (or Windows does so automatically after a number of days).

Some of those files will be locked, so you may not be able to copy the programs to their normal location if there's not enough room. Even if you *do* copy or move program files, note that those requiring installation to set PATH, Registry and other data, may not be fully usable.

After you've decided that all needed files have been recovered, perform Cleanup to get back disk space:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to show *Explorer*.
- Right-click on the C: drive and select *Properties*.
- Click the *Disk Cleanup* button.
- Click *Cleanup system files*.

[image: Windows Cleanup dlg]

- Eventually, you'll see the option for *Windows Update Cleanup*. Select it and wait... patiently. This may take hours on some systems, but should free up much space.

[image: Windows Update Cleanup dlg]